# Share viewmodel between multiple fragments in Bottom Navigation with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I have app, where i'm using fragment with navHost and connected navigation graph to it. This fragment, let's call it main fragment needs to download some data, that will be used by each of the tabs in bottom navigation. This looks like perfect usage of Shared ViewModel.

But there is no obvious way of using it with bottom navigation. There is a method `navGraphViewModels()` used with kotlin delegate:

```
val parentViewModel: CourtDetailRootVM by navGraphViewModels(R.id.court_detail)
```

but that produces Exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID 2131296449 is on the NavController's back stack
```

because according to documentation this method is looking for a viewModel that is on the current backstack, which is not the case with bottom navigation!

There are some other ways of getting parent viewModel but all of them requires reusage of ViewModelFactory. I can not use that, because my factory has constructor with some arguments, that need to be passed, and I don't have access to this arguments on child fragments.

So, I'm stuck and can't see any possible solution for this rather trivial issue

Comment: There're two ways you can achieve that: 1. Share ViewModels by activity context. if this is not feasible then 2. Make headless fragment that provides this data for you.

Comment: This is VERY tricky if you need to support a Multi-Stack on your bottom navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem twice.

1. The 1st issue was that I was created a new navigation file and used . This should technically work, but I was getting the same error.
   So I fixed it by selecting all the fragments that need to be grouped together inside the nav graph and `right-click->move to nested graph->new graph`

which will create something like this:

```
<navigation 
    android:id="@+id/checkout_graph" 
    app:startDestination="@id/cartFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/orderSummaryFragment".../>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/addressFragment" .../>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/paymentFragment" .../>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/cartFragment" .../>

</navigation>
```

Now, inside the fragments when you initialize the ViewModel do this

```
val viewModel: CheckoutViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.checkout_graph)
```

If you need to pass the viewmodel factory(may be for injecting the viewmodel) you can do it like this:

```
val viewModel: CheckoutViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.checkout_graph) { viewModelFactory }
```

2. The 2nd issue was a mistake of the Id that I was using while initializing the ViewModel. So make sure you are using the navGraph that is currently being used to initialize your ViewModel.

Comment: "defaultViewModelProviderFactory" with hilt